# How do I stop YouTube from playing the next recommended video?

Tags: youtube

After you end viewing a video in YouTube, the next recommended video is automatically played as a miniature. I find it incredibly annoying.

Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like some [users on the YouTube help forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=62493dec6b3bd60a&hl=en) have found that deleting all browser cookies related to YouTube will disable this "feature."

Comment: Good :) my limited bandwidth will no longer suffer from playing unrequested videos ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This can be changed in your user account settings now. Autoplay is enabled by default but you can switch it off.

Answer (score -2):

Install greasemonkey and use this script:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/71191

Comment: Why? Please add an explanation to your answer, external sites might vanish eventually.

Comment: Where's the link to Greasemoney? How to install it? How to use the script? Is this a web application you're suggesting?